# How to omit similar results in elastic search DSL query just like other search engines?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using **ElasticSearch** for storing some documents to create a search engine, everything works perfectly.

we may store similar documents in our elastic cloud.

I can see that some search engines omit similar data like **Google**.

Check out this message at the bottom of Google's result:

[image]

I need to implement exactly this, I want to know is there any way to omit similar documents in query results using **ElasticSearch** and give this option to the user that he either wants to see all results or not?

any suggestions, please?

**UPDATE**

I decided to add more information to make it clear.
consider these two documents below:

> Node.js is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript
> engine.

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.

there are a lot of documents like these in my elastic index. how can I omit similars and just show one of them in the DSL query?

is there any way to achieve this or need AI, ML, and these kinds of stuff to implement this?

Comment: Yes, there is, but can you show how your query currently looks like?

Comment: @Val consider it as a simple match query, BTW I have just updated my thread. thank you

Comment: Using `dense_vector` for encoding/measuring the semantic proximity of search results is probably one component of the solution. This article provides some insights: https://medium.com/gsi-technology/scalable-semantic-vector-search-with-elasticsearch-e79f9145ba8e

Comment: Have you had a look at the dense_vector option I linked to above?

Answer (score -2):

You can use **collapse** parameter to collapse search results based on field values for example, the following search collapses results by user.id and sorts them by `http.response.bytes`.

```
GET /my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "GET /search"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user.id"                
  },
  "sort": [ "http.response.bytes" ],  
  "from": 10                          
}
```

For more information you can check Elastic official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html#collapse-search-results).

Comment: thank you, I have seen this parameter but it's not useful here, I have just updated my question.

Comment: @ParsaMirHassannia, if you want to exclude documents that are similiar to eachother you don't have any option rather than using NLP and ML. You should calculate distance of document to eachothers and then have a matrix that shows similarity of each document to another one, in this case you can exclude documents that are similar to each other. I don't think so you can do this step in ES easily best approach will be to run this step after getting result from ES and do the filtering there. There is a good blog post about it https://rebeccabilbro.github.io/intro-doc-similarity-with-elasticsearch/.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. please update your answer and write down what you have commented with a simple example of how to implement this feature, then I can accept your answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

In order to solve your issue, you need to define what do you mean by "similar".

Google has a custom definition for it, that works for webpages. That definition is based on domains - you know, not to get flooded by results from one domain, but also based on the content - Google ranks low copied webpages.

You need to define a metrics that is specific for your documents. It is usually based on one specific property, the determinant field. What will be your determinant- you know it. If you have a forum engine, the topicID is a good choice. If you have a product catalog, the leaf categoryID will be the best.

There are two ways to achieve this goal.

1. Collapsing

This does exactly what you want. You can define the determinant field in your document, you can define what you want to show as a detail, etc. The [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) gives you lots of hints.

This will give you *exact results*, no matter how many shards you have, though it's a bit heavier operation.

2. Aggregation + Sampling

In this solution you create an aggregation, and use a sampler to pick some sample documents for you. Something like this:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "sample": {
            "diversified_sampler": {
                "field": "topicId",
                "shard_size": 200,
                "max_docs_per_value": 1
            },
```

This solution is faster, because - unlike `collapse` - it does not issue subqueries for all groups. The disadvantage is that this solution may not count exactly when using multiple shards. Also, you cannot specify ordering for the sampler - it always works by relevance.

There is an interesting discussion about comparing the two approaches on an [ElasticSearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/performance-aggregations-vs-collapsing/156295), worth to read it through.

Comment: I don't think that Google omits similar documents based on just domains, I think there are more complex algorithms than just not get flooded by results from one domain.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but collapsing is not useful here, I tested it and it didn't work as I expected.

Comment: Google has at least 500 developers working on it for 20 years. Of course, it is not possible to emulate the exact  behavior with 1 ES query - but this is the closest alternative that we have.

Comment: How about the sampling? was it working? You can adjust the per-group hits to 2-3, and manually post-process the results in code, if you want.

Comment: I'm not talking about implementing the algorithm of the world's first company with a simple query. the things that you mentioned about domains or category ID or topic ID are not the things that I mentioned in this thread. the things that you have mentioned are unique identifiers, not similar document recognition. I updated my question, thank you for your help.